# Symfony cookie is deleted after redirection

Tags: symfony, cookies

I know there was a few topics about this but I get see what I've done wrong.

my function for setting cookie is

```
public function createCookie($city)
{
    $expire = time() + (3600 * 24 * 90);
    $cookie = new Cookie('calendar_dev_city', $city, $expire, '/', 'cal.dev', false, false);

    $response = new Response();
    $response->headers->setCookie($cookie);
    $response->sendHeaders();
}
```

if I dump headers right at the end of this function I can see the cookie is set but after redirection it is gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to return that `Response` in a controller action.

```
<?php
// ...
public function pageAction() {
  $response = Response::create();
  $cookie = $this->makeCookie();
  $response->headers->setCookie($cookie);

  $response->setContent('thank you for setting the cookie!');

  return $response;
}

private function makeCookie() {
  $cookie = new Cookie(/* */);
  return $cookie;
}
```